# Topologically self-similar and self-dissimilar spaces

Tags: general-topology

Earlier today, I was leafing through Munkre's Topology, and I saw an exercise that said "prove that $(0, 1)$, $[0, 1)$, and $[0, 1]$ are all topologically distinct spaces". The hint provided suggested observing what happens when you remove a point from each space, the idea being, "removing any point from the first space disconnects it, removing more than one point from the second disconnects it, but you can remove up to two points before disconnecting the third space". However, it put me in mind of an incorrect proof that goes something like this: "If you remove $1$ from our second space, you get $(0, 1)$. **You cannot have a subspace homeomorphic to the ambient space**, so $(0, 1]$ and $(0, 1)$ are topologically distinct".

Of course, the bolded passage isn't true at all: $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0, 1)$ are homeomorphic. However, it made me wonder: is there (1) any topological space where this is true? **Namely, is there a topological space $X$ such that for all proper subsets $Y$, $X \not\simeq Y$, where $Y$ is equipped with the subspace topology.** This is obviously true for finite spaces, but that is because of cardinality concerns, not topological concerns. It also made me wonder if (2) there is any space where the negative result is true. Namely: **Is there a space $X$ such that any subspace $Y$ with the same cardinality of $X$ is homeomorphic to $X$?** I have added the cardinality clause as this result is false otherwise, again for cardinality concerns.  There's the discrete topology of course, but are there any more interesting choices?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, any space with a finite number of connected components and a topology fine enough to distinguish them cannot be homeomorphic to its subspaces.  (... because connected components are preserved under homeomorphism.)  So $X$ a finite collection of disjoint open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ inheriting the subspace topology is an example.  (This isn't really different from your finite sets example.)

The circle (as the quotient space $[0,1] / \{0,1\}$ where the interval inherits its topology from $\mathbb{R}$) might be a better example.  The circle is doubly connected (i.e., you must delete two points to disconnect it).  If you take a strict subset, you either get one or more than one connected components.  If the subset has more than one connected component, it is not homeomorphic to the circle.  If it has one connected component, then it is homeomorphic to an interval, not the circle.

Various trees and graphs (as studied in discrete math) are also examples of spaces where subspaces are not homeomorphic to the whole space.

Your second question seems unlikely unless the topology is coarse.  If $X$ has a fine enough topology, you can always find enough points, each with a connected open neighborhood (abbreviated "ball") which balls are pairwise disconnected, to have more balls than there are connected components of $X$, take $Y$ be the the union of those balls, and have a subset of $X$ that is not homeomorphic to $X$ (since it has more connected components than $X$).  I don't know how far down the spectrum of [separation axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom) one must go (that is, how coarse the topology must be) before variations and adaptations of this argument fail.

Comment: With regard to the second question, Hausdorff doesn't imply locally connected...

Comment: @BrianMoehring : Yes.  I don't know why I wrote that...

Comment: $S^1$ is a very good example! I believe $S^2$ is a similar example. A proof might go something along the lines of: $S^2$ minus a single point is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. So, any proper subspace of $S^2$ is homeomorphic a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, you can't embed $S^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ because of (mumble mumble mumble I don't know a proof of this part), so $S^2$ is not homeomorphic to any proper subspace. I would wager the higher dimensional spheres are all examples of such a space.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Z}$ with the cofinite topology is an example of a self-similar space. A bijection will carry a cofinite set to a cofinite set, and the preimage of a cofinite set is also a cofinite set, so any bijection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to an infinite subspace will be a homeomorphism.